# How to store an select option values with multidimensional array type name fields in php mysql

Tags: php

I have an array like below.

```
 $permis =array(
 'employee' => array(
      'myprofile' => array(
        'default' => '0', 'personal' => '0', 'job' => '0', 'leave' => '0', 'permission' => '0', 'bonus & commision' => '0', 'document' => '0', 'emergency contact' => '0', 'benifits' => '0'
        ),
        'viewallemployee' => array(
        'default' => '0', 'personal' => '0', 'job' => '0', 'leave' => '0', 'permission' => '0', 'bonus & commision' => '0', 'document' => '0', 'emergency contact' => '0', 'benifits' => '0', 'notes' => '0', 'onboard' => '0', 'offboard' => '0', 'charts' => '0'
        )
    )
);
```

i am using for each in to this array and get the output like below :

```
    <?php

 foreach($permis as $key => $myprofile){

    $module = $key;
    foreach($myprofile as $key => $profile){
    $submodule = $key;

        foreach($profile as $key => $data){


        ?>

<td><?php echo $module; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $submodule; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $key; ?></td>
<td>
<?php echo $submodule.$key; ?>
<select name="<?php $submodule.$key; ?>">
<option value='<?php $data ?>'><?php echo $data; ?></option>
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
</select>
</td>

</tr>
<?php
}
    }

}

?>
```

My question is i want to store my select option values into my mysql database tabel with arrayname and keyname example

myprofile default 0
myprofile personal 0 etc.

How to do this. please anyone help me

Comment: You can create a table having three columns. ID, option, value. So now you can store key in the option and its value inside the value column of table

Comment: my above code is right or wrong ( for declaring select option name )

Answer (score 0):

you can use json_encode to convert array into string and then you can store in database. OR you can use serialize() to convert array into storable format in Mysql.

Try this:

```
json_encode($permis); // Can be stored in Database
```

OR this:

```
serialize($permis); // Can be stored in Database
```